# Doctrine could not create db named 'Symfony'

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello console gives this issue while trying create db via console. I am using uniform server under windows 7 and trying to learn Symfony. It says it could not find driver which is pdo_mysql but i'm using pdo already with native php code. How will i fix it? Thank you.

SOLVED.
SOLUTION: I activated extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll in cli version of php.ini and restart apache.

Comment: please add the solution as an answer to this question and then mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. 
SOLUTION: I activated extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll in cli version of php.ini and restart apache.